# Ionic Cordova Crosswalk breaks Ionic Native Transition Functionality

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I am using ionic native transitions like this:

```
$ionicNativeTransitions.stateGo('app.search', {}, {}, 
        {
            "slowdownfactor"   : 0, 
            "direction": "right", 
            "duration": 400, 
            "iosdelay": -1, 
            " androiddelay": -1,
            " winphonedelay": 0
        })
```

I just installed crosswalk plugin using:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

I noticed though, when I use the back button that's on the page, there is a glitch where the screen turns black for a few seconds then goes back. Has anyone faced this issue before ?

Comment: I have this same issue. Did you ever resolve it?